# Circle packing within force graph nodes in D3?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout, circle-pack

I have a [Force Directed Graph](http://bl.ocks.org/1377729) that I've generated with D3 and within each node (which are represented as large circles) I'd like to pack in a bunch of smaller circles using D3's [Circle Packing](http://bl.ocks.org/4063530). Is it possible to use both of these layouts in one visualization? How does one insert a layout into a node?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out once I realized that svg elements were just regular dom nodes and I could manipulate them with jquery. I ended up created two svg locations, one for display and one for creation of svg objects. I built one object at a time in the builder location and then moved it off to somewhere else in order to work on the next guy. When I was ready I built the force graph on the main display and populated the nodes there with the circle packed nodes that I had saved off somewhere else.

Comment: Very cool! It would be very nice if you make your example accessible somehow.

Comment: I'm in the same position as @VividD, looking to achieve this and curious if there are code snippets that could offer some guidance.

Comment: Ah.  Very un-d3-ish.  I would like to see whether there's a d3 Way.